# Determining the day of the week for specified date in an arbitrary timezone with momentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Say I had an ISO date string with embedded timezone information, like `"2016-08-22T13:30:00-07:00"` (Here, the -07:00 specifies PST).  I'm looking for an elegant way to determine what day of the week it will be in that timezone on that date and time.  I've tried `moment.parseZone(datestring).weekday()` to no avail.  How can I make moment think in terms of the timezone specified in the string, instead of wherever the server happens to be?

Comment: Your code (`moment.parseZone(datestring).weekday()`) seems to work for me, what's wrong with it?

Comment: GingerPlusPlus is correct, your approach is fine.  What specifically doesn't work?  Show a complete example please, including what you got and what you expected.  Thanks.

Comment: Sooo... it actually does work.  There was just a bug in the surrounding code :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `moment(datestring).utcOffset(datestring).weekday()`, check the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/) for more explanation. Also there is a part of the [documntation on weekday](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/weekday/) which describes it as `locale aware` I am not sure if it maintains the time zone of the date while converting or defaults to your local/server location, I usually uses `moment.day()`, if it suits your use case, you can use it instead of `weekday()`.